# Quicksight filter for Multi-value parameter

Tags: database, filter, relational-database, amazon-quicksight

I have a table of activities, where each activity is tagged to multiple themes and personas. Sample data from the table below in attached image.
Table a: id, activity, theme (array with multiple values), persona (array with multiple values), reach(int)
table b: id, theme (single value per row)
table c: id, persona (single value per row)

Data is in a relational database.
Requirement to create a dashboard in QuickSight, showing the average of reach by different themes and Persona.

Current process: Added a 'Single value' parameter/ control for the values in theme column and then applied a filter on data using the parameter.
Filter type: Custom filter
Filter condition: Contains
Use parameters: selected the 'Single value' parameter.
Note: Not joining table a to b or c as it returns incorrect average of reach.

Result: This gives me a filter that can only select one value for theme at time.

Required result: To be able to filter for multiple themes and get the average reach.
Issue: Multi-value parameter is only compatible with equals/not equals filter. Cannot use 'contains' filter condition.

Is there a work-a-round?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUK8q.png)